# Значение выбранного селекта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как убрать зацикливание при выборе? использую плагин selecter

```js
$("select").selecter();
$('#price_direct_s').on("change", function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  alert(val);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://goryzovut.ru/assets/css/libs.min.css">
<div style="display: block;padding-top: 70px;">
  <select name="price_direct" id="price_direct_s">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script src="http://goryzovut.ru/assets/js/libs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Что-то тег `link` у вас потерялся..

Comment: не понял, что не так?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/link

Comment: все ровно не могу понять, при чем здесь link

Comment: помогите пожалуйста, голову сломал

Comment: @murfuc чего вы добиться то хотите вообще ? выводить значение при изменении ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо, событие `change` срабатывает при `blur`. Зацикливание происходит из-за `alert`.

Решение - не использовать `alert`.

```js
$("select").selecter();
$('#price_direct_s').on("change", function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://goryzovut.ru/assets/css/libs.min.css">
<div style="display: block;padding-top: 70px;">
  <select name="price_direct" id="price_direct_s">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script src="http://goryzovut.ru/assets/js/libs.min.js"></script>
```